# Converting RTF Dom Document back to RTF string

Tags: c#, dom, rtf

I need to change an RTF string so that all RTF tab tags (/tab) across the text, are replaced by any other character («tab», let's suppose).

This is necessary because this RTF string is going to be fed to an HTML converter, which ignores all /tab's in the string, since HTML doesn't support tabs. For that, I decided to replace this tag (/tab) with another symbol («tab»), that is later interpreted by the HTML filter, which adds   tags accordingly.
I accomplish all this by loading the RTF string into an RTF Dom Document, with the aid of RTF Dom Parser, and then changing all '\t' with the new symbol in the text nodes.
My problem now is on obtaining the new generated RTF string, according to the new DOM Tree.
I've searched everywhere but I can't seem to find any information on how to convert an RTF Dom Document back to RTF string.

```cs
private static void FilterRtf(string rtf)
{
    // RTF Dom Document creation
    RTFDomDocument document = new RTFDomDocument();

    // RTF Document Tree loading, according to RTF string
    document.LoadRTFText(rtf);

    // Replacement of tabulation text in paragraph nodes
    ReplaceIndentation(document);

    // RTF generated string, based on RTF Document Tree???

}
```

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have access to the `RichTextBox` you can pass the rtf to it and ask for the string it self. `RichTextBox.Rtf` to set the rtf text or load from a file `RichTextBox.LoadFile(String)` More info at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.richtextbox?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Camadas The thing is I don't have the RTF itself, I only have the RTF Dom Document object :/